# Java nullPointerException with getter and setters on an object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a nullPointerException below. Can someone explain why? Thanks!

```
private SpatialPooler spatialPooler;
private Region        region;
private Column        column33;


public void setUp()
{
    this.spatialPooler = new SpatialPooler();

    this.region = new Region(30, 40, 6, 8, 1.0f, 1, 1);

    this.column33 = this.region.getColumn(3, 3);
}

public void addActiveColumn(Column activeColumn)
{
    this.activeColumns.add(activeColumn); // nullPointerException here!
}

public Column getActiveColumn(int x, int y)
{
    for (Column activeColumn : this.activeColumns)
    {
        if (activeColumn.getX() == x && activeColumn.getY() == y)
        {
            return activeColumn;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// in a test class that is in the same package.
public void testGetAndAddActiveColumn()
{
    this.spatialPooler.addActiveColumn(this.column33);
    assertNull(this.spatialPooler.getActiveColumn(3, 3));

    this.column33.setActiveState(true);
    assertEquals(this.column33, this.spatialPooler.getActiveColumn(3, 3));
}
```

Comment: How do you call your `testGetAndAddActiveColumn`?

Comment: where I wrote the comment // nullPointException here!

Comment: By looking at the code it seems that `activeColumns` is a list.You need to initialize list of `activeColumns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show `activeColumns` being initialized anywhere.

If it's a List of *Column* objects, you should put this code somewhere:

```
List<Column> activeColumns = new ArrayList<Column>();
```

You could put it in a constructor, or just use the above code when you declare `activeColumns`

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException`s are mainly because you are using an uninitialized variable. I assume that activeColumns hasn't been initialized. It isn't a member so it wouldn't have scope inside that functio.  You can fix it a few ways

1) a local variable

2) add activeColumns as a member

3) change the behavior of the function